# Why am I getting multiple responses when I'm using async/await?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a simple voting web api for a class. I'm currently working on PUT and my code is working, but I'm getting a strange error in my command line terminal. Here is the code I'm using to call PUT:

```
async addVotes(item) {
      try {
            let response = await axios.put("/api/candidates/" + item._id);
            this.getItems();
            return true;
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
          console.log(item.name + " is checked");
    },

async submitVotes(items) {
      for (var item of this.items) {
        if (item.selected) {

          this.addVotes(item);
        }
        else {
          console.log(item.name + " is not checked");
        }
      }
    },
```

and here is the PUT code for the api:

```
app.put('/api/candidates/:id', async(req, res) => {
  console.log("initiated put(edit) request");
  try {
    let candidate = await Candidate.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    candidate.numVotes += 1;
    candidate.save();
    res.send(candidate);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

I'm getting an error saying this:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:357:8)
    at app.put (/var/www/html/MidRev/start.js:102:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13246) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/var/www/html/MidRev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:357:8)
    at app.put (/var/www/html/MidRev/start.js:106:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13246) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13246) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

From what I've researched online I'm getting this error because I'm getting more than one response, but I am using async/await so I don't understand why I should be getting that error.

Comment: You are calling `res.sendStatus` after you have called `send()` You don't need the `sendStatus(200)`

Comment: So do I just get rid of one, or swap them? I'm a little confused how responses work

Comment: Thank you! I just got rid of res.send(candidate) and it works!

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you add status to the response is incorrect.

Instead of

```
res.send(candidate);
res.sendStatus(200);
```

You should do it this way

```
res.status(200).send(candidate)
```

sendStatus sends an 'OK' message on top of setting the status code. You may refer to the Express API reference here https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Thank you for giving me the correct answer and an explanation!

Comment: Just to clarify, if I just deleted res.sendStatus(200); and just kept res.send(candidate); would that also do the same thing?

Comment: yes the default status code for res.send is 200 so res.status(200).send(candidate) is same as res.send(candidate) ..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your PUT API implementation in which you're sending the response twice:

1. res.send(candidate); // sending json response back to client
2. res.sendStatus(200); // trying to send response status

So if you're sending a json response then you do not need to send response status explicitly.

```
res.send(candidate); OR res.json(candidate);
```

However, if you want to specify the response status then you can do chaining like:

```
res.status(500).send({ error: "boo" });
```